# GUI for PHP in NetBeans?

Tags: php, user-interface, netbeans

Hi there I would kindly like to ask if NetBeans has any sort of GUI builder like the ones they offered for Java programming? Sorry for the noob Questions. If so, how do I install or use them? Thanks.

Comment: For PHP or for HTML? PHP core does not have anything like Java's Swing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not have this functionality as PHP does not have any GUI components built in. PHP is usually combined with HTML and CSS to render a view. Netbeans does not have a builder for HTML and CSS either so the answer is no.

Comment: Hi guys I am actually asking if the "NetBeans" program has a PHP GUI editor or builder. Sorry if i Misled you..

Answer (score 1):

The only GUI Builder I know for PHP is [Delphi for PHP](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-for-php), or it's new name RadPHP

for the new version there's a twenty video show some of it's features, you can look at them [here](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/joseleon/2010/06/17/twenty-video-milestone/)

Answer (score 0):

There are some primitive examples of IDE's that includes GUI components. But Netbeans does not have a GUI editor or builder for PHP. Soon enough IDE developers will include some standart components since there seems to be a rising demand for visual web development. To counter balance Visual Studio, the "php"ians will retaliate somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Now Netbeans version 7.3 beta support inbuilt gui builder for html5....

May be this will help us.